# Show $\frac{\cos x_1}{\cos x_2}=1-\frac{1}{2}(x_1^2-x_2^2)+\vert x\vert^3o(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

I have that

\begin{align}
\frac{\cos x_1}{\cos x_2}
&=\frac{1-\frac12x_1^2+o(\|x\|^3)}{1-\frac12 x_2^2+o(\|x\|^3)}\\
&=\left(1-\frac12x_1^2+o(\|x\|^3)\right)\left(1+\frac12 x_2^2+o(\|x\|^3)\right)\\
&=1+\frac{1}{2}x_2^2+\vert x\vert^3\ o(x)-\frac{1}{2}x_1^2-\frac{1}{4}x_1^2x_2^2-\frac{1}{2}x_1^2\vert x\vert^3o(x)
+\vert x\vert^3o(x)\\
&+\frac{1}{2}x_2^2\vert x\vert^3o(x)+\vert x\vert^6o(x)\\
&=1+\frac{1}{2}x_2^2-\frac{1}{2}x_1^2-\frac{1}{4}x_1^2x_2^2+\vert x\vert^3o(x).
\end{align}

But the correct answer should be $$\frac{\cos x_1}{\cos x_2}=1-\frac{1}{2}(x_1^2-x_2^2)+\vert x\vert^3\epsilon(x).$$

What is done wrong here?

Comment: What is $|x|$ as defined in the title? Is it $|(x_1+x_2)|$?

Comment: Norm of $x-0$. The limit of $\epsilon$ is zero as $x$ tends to zero.

Comment: How did you get your second equality?

Comment: I think you should either use $\|x\|$ or $|x|$, not both.

Comment: Most of all I'm curious to know why $-\frac{1}{4}x_1^2 x_2^2$ vanishes from the sum.

Comment: Simply because it goes into $o\bigl(\|x\|^3\bigr)$.

Comment: What is $x$?  you have $x_1, x_2$ on the left side but no $x$;  so $x$ mysteriously appears on the right side without a definition.  The explanation that $|x| =$ norm of $x-0$ does not mean much to me.

Comment: @Bernard but that is an independent term which is not multiplied by the o function. Therefore I assume we can't make arguments such as $c\dot o=o$ and so forth with this term.

Comment: Isn't $x$ supposed to be the vector $(x_1,x_2)$?

Comment: I was referring to the properties of the o function. That is, the sum of multiple o functions is just the o function, and multiplying it with a scalar yields the o function itself. This is why we can reduce terms from the sum.

Comment: Note that by the AM-GM inequality $$
x_1^2 x_2^2  \le \left( {\frac{{x_1^2  + x_2^2 }}{2}} \right)^2  = \left( {\frac{1}{2}\left| x \right|^2 } \right)^2  = \frac{1}{4}\left| x \right|^4 .
$$